# Implement "Search" like the App Store Search

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsxmlparser, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a search like the one used on the app store. i.e. when a user enters something, say "ABC", it immediately begins searching for ABC in an external database or something...
Is the source code available for the same or for something similar ?

Even though I have found examples of UISearchbar online, they are mostly on static data set (e.g. against a predefined array items) and I know how to implement that kind of Search. 
However in my case, the items to search for cannot be predefined, as they come dynamically from a API call (in an XML format) i.e. if the user types "ABC" I need to pass this to an NSURL "http://www.exturl.com/?searchTerm=ABC", which would then return me an XML file that I parse and need to show the results from.

I cannot find an example of something similar, even though I thought this could be soemthing quite common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the Apple is using which protocols(like REST,SOAP etc). 
But one thing I know that, While registering any App to the AppStore, they need to give some key words right?
While searching in the AppStore it will send the words to the server and it directly check in the word wise, not the character wise. So it is some what quick.

So, What I am saying, for searching it will take some time, that is not an issue I think.

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about real time searching. For that use this delegate method of protocol

```
<UISearchBarDelegate>

include this protocol in your .h file.

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

}
```

edit it according to your need, For eg, u can send database query in this method or can call any method.
If I am not clear, let me know